# A proper way of inserting built-in functions into VS Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

**Introduction**

I'm currently developing an application based on Bluegiga BLE-112 module. The module is programmable in BGScript scripting language. However, only editor I found, that has some kind of support for BGScript, is Notepad++, which does not suit my needs. Therefore, I started development of my own extension for Visual Studio Code (one available in the extension market is not working). I already went past through colorizer and error parsing, now I'm creating a part with code suggestions.

**Main problem**

I'd like to have [all functions, enumerations and events embedded in the language](https://www.silabs.com/documents/login/reference-manuals/Bluetooth_Smart_Software-BLE-1.6-API-RM.pdf#page=40) listed when I'm typing. I found that code snippets could be the way of achieving this. An example of snippet in JSON format that works as I expect looks like below.

```
"call attclient_indicate_confirm": {
    "prefix": "call attclient_indicate_confirm",
    "body": [
        "call attclient_indicate_confirm(${1:connection})(${2:result})"
    ],
    "description": "Send a acknowledge a received indication from a remote device."
}
```

`call` is a keyword indicating, that in this line a function is envoked. When snippet like this is stored in a proper JSON file, everything works fine - I start typing `call`, VS Code suggests a code snippets and I can use it.

*However*, creating a code snippet for [enumerations](https://www.silabs.com/documents/login/reference-manuals/Bluetooth_Smart_Software-BLE-1.6-API-RM.pdf#page=64) looks like an overkill, as enums have nothing variable - they should be inserted as-is.

**My question is:** are there any ways other than code snippets, that could be implemented inside an Visual Studio Code extension, for creating suggestions of enumerations in BGScript language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can register a [CompletionItemProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#CompletionItemProvider) via `registerCompletionItemProvider()` (see the [`languages` namespace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_languages)). This should cover all your use cases, as completion items can also use snippet insertion by making their `insertText` a `SnippetString`.

Often this (along with other providers) is implemented through an abstraction layer called the [Language Server Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) instead of using the VSCode API directly, which makes it editor-independent.

Comment: Firstly, thank You for Your support, Gama11. To clarify, completion items You mentioned can only be used with TypeScript/JavaScript? Extension I'm creating was made using `yo code -> New Language Support`, thus I have no *.ts or *.js files created by the generator. Should I convert my extension to a normal TypeScript one or can I use completion items in some JSON file?

Comment: Yes, you will have to do this programatically. TypeScript and JavaScript are probably the two "standard options". Language servers are actually language-agnostic and could be implemented in any language that supports socket communication.