# VSCode IntelliSense keywords for language extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a language extension and would like to add keywords to be suggested for autocompletion by IntelliSense.  For instance, the Python extension suggests the `try` keyword, as shown in the image below.

[image: Python's try keyword]

IntelliSense has keyword completions, as shown in its [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions), which has the icon [image: keyword icon] in the list.  How do you define the list of keywords for IntelliSense to suggest?

Comment: The way the question is worded seems awfully specific, which makes me think I might be missing something - doesn't seem like there would be any difference between completion items for keywords and others? Apart from the icon you set for the CompletionItem, of course.

Comment: I'm just looking for these words to come up as completion options at all.  I don't think it's appropriate to include them as snippets, but that's the only way I know to add completion options.

Comment: What you're looking for is the CompletionItemProvider API, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50761525/a-proper-way-of-inserting-built-in-functions-into-vs-code-extension/50774760#50774760 for instance.